# Python pip path

Tags: shell, pip, pythonpath

This is a ridiculously simple question, but bear with me, because i didn't see anyone ask it.

I have Anaconda installed on my Mac. It's taking all sorts of forever to solve the environment on a package install, and I don't have time to troubleshoot now, so I decided to install via pip. Works great, only now I don't know where the package is installed.

How can I check my pip `PYTHONPATH` location so that I can add that location to my other paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip show <package name>`

I am not really experienced with python but once similar thing happend with me and i used this.